# Start Minecraft_Server.jar via PHP Exec() or similar function

Tags: java, php, jar, amazon-ec2, minecraft

I'm trying to build a script that starts `minecraft_server.jar` (location: user directory / mineserver / minecraft_server.jar ).

I have PHP and Apache installed, and I'm trying trying to start the server JAR from `/var/www/html/interface.php`.

Via console, the server starts fine by running:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar mineserver/minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

... from the user directory. So in the `interface.php` file I have the following (note location listed above):

```
system('java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/ec2-user/mineserver/minecraft_server.jar nogui', $retval);
```

But the server never starts after I visit the file. What am I doing wrong?

### Thanks for any and all clues.

I want to say thank you for your help on Thanksgiving. While I haven't found the solution yet, I appreciate the efforts. Thanks again.

Comment: Permission issue? Perhaps that the user under which Apache is running cannot read the file.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie - what user does Apache typically run under?

Comment: I assume that `system` isn't disabled? If it isn't, what is the result of the `system` call?

Comment: @Unobtainium I tried system the same way and I couldn't get the server to start.

Comment: @weingage What about `$result = shell_exec('java ...'); var_dump($result);`? What does it print?

Comment: @Unobtainium it returns NULL

Comment: @weingage Well, that result isn't very informative... The manual says that `NULL` is returned when an error occurs.

Comment: @Unobtainium Lets go back to the system() command ... how can i check to see if it's disabled?

Comment: @weingage `$result = system('ls'); var_dump($result);` -- if that is successful, then it isn't disabled.

Comment: @Unobtainium Sadly, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the error log? It's at `/var/log/httpd` by default. If anything went wrong, it should be there. Otherwise, it could be starting wrong and I would recommend launching it in a [screen](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) so you can hop in and check on anything it's doing.

Install `screen` through whatever method your distribution uses, and then change the launch string to be:


`screen -dmS "minecraft" java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/ec2-user/mineserver/minecraft_server.jar nogui`

Comment: Does the part of your code "server" need to be changed to something specific to my setup? (aka a server name or something I am unaware of )

Comment: No, that's the name of the screen that will be launching. If you access the php file, you should be able to then go to prompt and use <code>screen -x NAME</code> to access the screen (if it ran properly) - assuming you named it "server", the command would be <code>screen -x server</code>

Comment: Screen was installed and I replaced my exec() code with yours above to no avail. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

PS: I set $success = exec() and echoed it back at the end, but got nothing. Not sure if that helps clue anything in.

Comment: Sounds more like you have an error and the script isn't completing, there's nothing of interest in the error log?

Comment: [Fri Nov 23 03:40:16 2012] [error] [ip address] File does not exist:
/var/www/html/favicon.ico
Unable to access jarfile /home/e
sh: line 1: c2-user/mineserver/minecraft_server.jar: No such file or directory --- so does it look like it isn't finding the file?

Comment: Yeah. Try running the following to make sure the file is there as expected: ls /home/ec2-user/mineserver/ | grep minecraft_server.jar

Comment: Ignore that error - I had a space in my code checking a suggestion above that threw that error.

Comment: @weingage Is the `.jar` file listed when you execute `$result = shell_exec('ls /home/ec2-user/mineserver/'); var_dump($result);`? **EDIT:** Oops, too late - H31IX already mentioned that.

Comment: @Unobtainium , H31IX - Breakthrough, I think. I ran the screen command in console and it started the server fine. So why would running it inside of exec() change anything? Permissions?

Comment: Code I ran (from /var/www/html/) :

screen -dmS "minecraft" java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -
jar /home/ec2-user/mineserver/minecraft_server.jar nogui

server started fine.

Comment: That's possible. See this thread on running screen with permissions: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/32088-screen-throws-permission-denied.html

Comment: I read that, but didn't see a solution - not sure what to look for. My guess is that the screen won't start using the user apache is running under (which is 'apache'). SO i just need to get it to run as 'ec2-user' or 'root' (unless otherwise recommended)

Comment: There's not as much vulnerability running a minecraft server as root as some web applications, but it's certainly not ideal (Working at Bukkit I've seen people submit plugins which, if run this way, can allow any user to delete any file off the server) Running it as your ec2 user would be the best course of action if it works.

Comment: How would you write that screen command that I said worked above to run as ec2-user rather than under apache (which I think is default via php)?

Answer (score 2):

The command will be executed with the permissions, and the environment of whatever user account the web server runs under.

In particular, it may have a different `PATH` entry, and the `java` command might not even be found, or it might be found somewhere else etc...

Also, be aware of what current working directory it is inheriting from your PHP script.

See `exec()` and check the output to help yourself do some basic debugging.

Also, you probably want something more like

```
exec('nohup java etc... > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

so that the process gets properly backgrounded and disconnected from the webserver parent process.